# Graphical abstract in beamer EDITED

Tags: beamer, abstract

I have the following `beamer` presentation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}

\section{First}
\begin{frame}[label=A]
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\framewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
\end{frame}

\section{Second}
\begin{frame}[label=B]
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\framewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
\end{frame}

\section{Third}
\begin{frame}[label=C]
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\framewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}
\end{frame}

\section{Fourth}
\begin{frame}[label=D]
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\framewidth]{example-image} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Graphical abstract}

I would like here to have a reduced view of 
frames A, B, C and D on one frame.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The last frame should be a kind of graphical
abstract of the presentation, i.e., I would like it to contain a reduced view of frames A, B, C, and D
on one frame.

How should I achieve that?

Following the comments by Sam Carter below, I have tried the following simple and rogue solution :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}

\section{First}
\begin{frame}[label=A]
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\framewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
\end{frame}

\section{Second}
\begin{frame}[label=B]
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\framewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
\end{frame}

\section{Third}
\begin{frame}[label=C]
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\framewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}
\end{frame}

\section{Fourth}
\begin{frame}[label=D]
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\framewidth]{example-image}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Graphical abstract}

I would like here to have a reduced view of frames A, 
B, C and D one one frame.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\scalebox{0.2}{\againframe{A}}\scalebox{0.2}{\againframe{B}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

that gives me almost what I want, except that beamer is adding a lot of junk between my scaled frames.

Any ideas along thses line or am I being too rogue with `beamer`.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69991/thumbnails-of-other-frames-in-beamer

Comment: off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}`, beamer loads it automatically

Comment: ... there are also pdfviewer like pdfpc which offer such overviews via a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for the comment on `graphicx`. I'll have a  look at the question you pointed out.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz OK. I now have a better grip on the problem. Would have liked a simpler solution but do not know if this is possible.

Comment: The simple solution is to use a pdf viewer who can do this :)

Comment: You can't use againframe inside of another frame.

Comment: ... and although it is an hour later now, `\usepackage{graphicx}` is still not necessary :)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Sorry: cut and paste error.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I said my solution was rogue. But bizarrely it almost works.

Comment: "almost works" is a bit exaggerated. It does not throw an error because beamer restores the normal latex definition of `\frame` inside of beamer frames. This latex definition of frame has nothing to do with the beamer definition of frame and basically just dumps the content of the frame into your overview frame. In your case with the big image, the result will have some similarity, but it will explode spectacularly as soon as the frame contains anything more complex.

Answer (score -1):

This code places the previous four frames into minipages, each using `\againframe`. Its width is controlled by the width of the minipage. Notice that the assembly is **outside** of a frame.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{First}
    \begin{frame}[label=A]
        \noindent\includegraphics[width=\framewidth]{example-image-a.jpg}
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Second}
    \begin{frame}[label=B]
        \noindent\includegraphics[width=\framewidth]{example-image-b.jpg}
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Third}
    \begin{frame}[label=C]
        \noindent\includegraphics[width=\framewidth]{example-image-c.jpg}
    \end{frame}
    
    \section{Fourth}
    \begin{frame}[label=D]
        \noindent\includegraphics[width=\framewidth]{example-image}
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Graphical abstract}
        
        I would like here to have a reduced view of frames A, 
        B, C and D one one frame.
    \end{frame}
    % **********             added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \vspace*{-1cm}
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\framewidth}
    \againframe{A}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\framewidth}
    \againframe{B}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\framewidth}
    \againframe{C}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.2\framewidth}
    \againframe{D}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```